# How to find Current open Cursors in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, database-cursor

What is the query to find the number of current open cursors in an Oracle Instance?

Also, what is the accuracy/update frequency of this data?

I am using Oracle 10gR2

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Total cursors open, by session:

```
select a.value, s.username, s.sid, s.serial#
from v$sesstat a, v$statname b, v$session s
where a.statistic# = b.statistic#  and s.sid=a.sid
and b.name = 'opened cursors current';
```

Source: http://www.orafaq.com/node/758

As far as I know queries on v$ views are based on pseudo-tables ("x$" tables) that point directly to the relevant portions of the SGA, so you can't get more accurate than that; however this also means that it is point-in-time (i.e. dirty read).

Comment: These 'opened cursors current' are lazily reaped by the Oracle table server; so the number you see for your application may be anomalously high without meaning you made a mistake.

See  http://www.orafaq.com/node/758

Comment: If this doesn't work for you, try first granting yourself the required privileges with command: sqlplus "/ as sysdba"

Answer (score 14):

```
select  sql_text, count(*) as "OPEN CURSORS", user_name from v$open_cursor
group by sql_text, user_name order by count(*) desc;
```

appears to work for me.

Answer (score 9):

Here's how to find open cursors that have been parsed.  You need to be logged in as a user with access to v$open_cursor and v$session.

```
COLUMN USER_NAME FORMAT A15

SELECT s.machine, oc.user_name, oc.sql_text, count(1) 
FROM v$open_cursor oc, v$session s
WHERE oc.sid = s.sid
GROUP BY user_name, sql_text, machine
HAVING COUNT(1) > 2
ORDER BY count(1) DESC
;
```

If gives you part of the SQL text so it can be useful for identifying leaky applications.  If a cursor has not been parsed, then it does not appear here.  Note that Oralce will sometimes keep things open longer than you do.

Comment: Actually, this is a complex situation.  v$open_cursor happens to show cached statements.

Open cursors (the resource that can be hammered if you have a cursor / ResultSet leak) is in  v$sessstat in a row named 'opened cursors current'.

Comment: @Ollie: But how does that help you identify the SQL statement that is leaking?

Comment: This select shows you the actual SQL code that opened the cursors, great for debugging ! +1 from me

Answer (score 3):

1)your id should have sys dba access
2)

```
select sum(a.value) total_cur, avg(a.value) avg_cur, max(a.value) max_cur, 
 s.username, s.machine
 from v$sesstat a, v$statname b, v$session s 
 where a.statistic# = b.statistic# and s.sid=a.sid
 and b.name = 'opened cursors current' 
 group by s.username, s.machine
 order by 1 desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has a page for this issue with SQL and trouble shooting suggestions.

"Troubleshooting Open Cursor Issues"
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E40329_01/admin.1112/e27149/cursor.htm#OMADM5352

Answer (score 1):

I would use this quick SQL to compare the highest current use compared to the max allowed. This will allow you to immediately see if any process has a dangerously high use of cursors.

```
SELECT MAX (a.VALUE) AS highest_open_cur, p.VALUE AS max_open_cur
FROM v$sesstat a, v$statname b, v$parameter p
WHERE a.statistic# = b.statistic#
AND b.name = 'opened cursors current'
AND p.name = 'open_cursors'
GROUP BY p.VALUE;
```

As is probably clear from the above SQL, the OPEN_CURSORS value is an Oracle parameter and can be found at runtime like this.

```
SELECT * FROM v$parameter WHERE NAME = 'open_cursors';
```

You may need to be sysdba or equivalent to query the above tables.

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this:

```
select 
  user_name, 
  count(*) as "OPEN CURSORS" 
from 
  v$open_cursor 
group by 
  user_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

This could work:

```
SELECT    sql_text "SQL Query", 
          Count(*) AS "Open Cursors" 
FROM      v$open_cursor 
GROUP BY  sql_text 
HAVING    Count(*) > 2 
ORDER BY  Count(*) DESC;
```