# How to solve ORA-29471 on dbms_sql.open_cursor?

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I'm using Oracle 11.2.0.1.0 and am trying to get the dbms_sql package to work.
However, I keep getting the ORA-29471 error, as shown below:

```
DECLARE
  c INTEGER;
BEGIN
  c := dbms_sql.open_cursor();
END;

ORA-29471: DBMS_SQL access denied
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1017
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

The oracle [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sql.htm#i1027587) say the following about this:

> Checks are made when binding and executing. Optionally, checks may be
>   performed for every single DBMS_SQL subprogram call. The check is:
>
> - The current_user is the same on calling the subprogram as it was on calling the most recent parse.
> - The enabled roles on calling the subprogram must be a superset of the enabled roles on calling the most recent parse.
>
> Consistent with the use of definer's rights subprograms, roles do not
>   apply. If either check fails, and ORA-29470 error is raised.

As far as I can tell, both conditions don't apply to my code, because the code does not cross schemas.

The Oracle [support](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=245680528703537&id=556301.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=gh5mnitqd_107) (requires login) website proposes that I explicitly add the security_level parameter into dbms_sql.open_cursor. Adding any of the values (0/1/2) doesn't solve the issue.

The puzzling thing for me is that I get the error at the `dbms_sql.open_cursor`, which is where the security level is first defined.

The support website also proposes a workaround that involves setting:

```
alter system set "_dbms_sql_security_level" = 384 scope=spfile;
```

I haven't tried that yet. I prefer to think of it as a last resort, because it involves disabling a security layer and it is an unsupported oracle feature. Hardly ideal circumstances for production use. Also, it doesn't really solve the issue at all, just hides it.

How can I solve this error?

Comment: A solution could be to have a look into the v$Session view. Morer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010898/how-to-find-current-open-cursors-in-oracle).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The only reason(cannot see another one at this moment) why your code raises the `ORA-29471` is you already made `dbms_sql` inoperable in your session by providing an invalid cursor ID:

```
/* dbsm_sql detects invalid cursor ID in this session  */ 
SQL> declare
  2    c_1 number := 5;  -- invalid cursor ID. There is no cursor 
  3    l_res boolean;    -- opened with ID = 5     
  4  begin
  5    l_res := dbms_sql.is_open(c_1);
  6  end;
  7  /
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29471: DBMS_SQL access denied 
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1104 
ORA-06512: at line 5 


/* An attempt to execute this simple anonymous PL/SQL block after 
   an invalid cursor ID has already been detected by the dbms_sql 
   in the current session will lead to ORA-29471 error  
*/

SQL> declare
  2    c_2 number;
  3  begin
  4    c_2 := dbms_sql.open_cursor();
  5  end;
  6  /
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29471: DBMS_SQL access denied 
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1084 
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

Try to execute that code in a **newly established session**.

Comment: Dammit.  I was about to say exactly the same thing, but you beat me to it. +1

Comment: I had just repro'd the error in the same way as you and was about to paste the SQL*Plus output into my answer when I saw your answer.  If I was that upset about it I wouldn't have upvoted your post. :)

Comment: You are correct. Establishing a new session fixed the issue. I can't believe I spent over an hour without finding that out. Thanks!

Comment: @Nicholas Krasnov

How can we identify a particular session is invalidated for DBMS_SQL?

Comment: I'm in Oracle SQL Developer. New session worked. But it actually does not mean opening a new sheet but closing the Developer and Start new.

Comment: @NickKrasnov wow I can't believe that reopening a new session fixes the issue. I was able to save hours thanks to your answer. Can I ask you to maybe emphasize the _establish new connection_ part? Some non-eagle-eyed users may not realize this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to have a look into the `v$Session` view.

If the cursor exists in the list, then it means you can still us it. Then identify it from its `sql_id`, and you can check. Here you generate the list:

```
  select  sql_id, sql_text, count(*) as "OPEN CURSORS", user_name 
   from v$open_cursor
  where user_name <>'SYS' 
group by sql_text, user_name 
order by count(*) desc;
```

More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010898/how-to-find-current-open-cursors-in-oracle).